# oracle insert xml in xmltype column using jdbctemplate batchupdate results in ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, batch-updates

I have a spring boot app that has a list of entity that I'm passing to the below batch insert but results in `ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column`. Not very sure why this is happening:

```
(...)
batchInsert(books, 100);
(...)

public int[][] batchInsert(List<Book> books, int batchSize) {
    return jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
            "insert into books (bookId, name, price, xml) values(?,?,?,?)",
            books,
            batchSize,
            new ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<Book>() {
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, Book argument) 
                    throws SQLException {
                    ps.setString(1, argument.getBookId());
                    ps.setString(2, argument.getName());
                    ps.setBigDecimal(3, argument.getPrice());
                    ps.setString(4, argument.getXml());
                }
            });
}
```

oracle datatype for the xml column in the table is: `XML SYS.XMLTYPE`

and the model:

```
@Type(type="com.sample.util.HibernateXMLType")
@Column(name = "XML", columnDefinition="XDB.XMLTYPE")
private String xml;
```

The error is only happening for some specific XMLs, not all of them. Probably because of the size of those specific XMLs, not very sure.

I have tried below approaches but still getting the same error:

```
1.
SQLXML xmlObject = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().createSQLXML();
xmlObject.setString(argument.getXml());
ps.setSQLXML(4, xmlObject);

2.
ps.setClob(4, new StringReader(argument.getXml()));
```

Now, I've also used JPA like below, which is working with the same data type, only thing is that it is very slow compared to jdbctemplate, perhaps by the fact that it has to do a select before the insert to check whether the entity is present or no:

```
bookRepo.saveAll(books);
```

Comment: Various Oracle host programming interfaces automatically define their datatypes based on your host language datatypes and its ability to map between them. Since there is a 4KB limit to a varchar2 field in Oracle, any host string greater than 4000 bytes (or 2000 depending on the database characterset) could potentially overflow a varchar2, so it automatically upconverts the datatype to a LONG. But LONGs are horridly restricted to the point of being nearly unusable. Hence the error. Either keep your host variables < 4KB/2KB or explicitly work with CLOBs instead. Implementation varies by platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ps.setSQLXML` for xmltype: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlxml.html

But don't forget to initialize it properly:

```java
 SQLXML sqlxml = ps.getConnection().createSQLXML();
 try {
  sqlxml.setString(argument.getXml());
  ps.setSQLXML(4, sqlxml);
 } finally {
  sqlxml.free();
 }
}
```

Comment: please refer to my updated post

Comment: @Somebody ah, I see... Looks like you have that problem not with XML, but with `bookid` or `name`. You can exclude xml from your tests and try to trace other values properly. I suspect that bookId or name column definition is shorter than values you are trying to insert

Comment: your approach worked at the end, I had it a little differently